# Can I contact my friends to post reviews for my app in the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore

I am releasing a new app to the App Store, and I think that I would be great if I can contact my friends to post reviews on the app. But Apple says that developers that attempt to fake reviews will be expelled from the Developer Program, as indicated in [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata) rule 3.10. However, I also saw an article on the Web that recommends the approach of contacting your friends and acquaintances to post a review on the App Store for your app ([thinkapps.com/blog/launch/create-successful-app-4-ways-grow-users](http://thinkapps.com/blog/launch/create-successful-app-4-ways-grow-users/), in section *Where to Start/Launch/Step 1*). So will I be expelled from the Developer Program if I contact my friends to post reviews for my app? Thanks very much.

Comment: If you do it , then do it professionally.  They should use they own computers (unique IP), and they emails ect.. Other than that, there is no way for Apple to make the link.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Then what does Apple exactly mean in detail in "faking reviews"?

Comment: I do not know, but I assume, they can track the IP and the email ect... showing it was you multiple times (faking it) to be someone else. So if you have friends in newerland then you are fine :). Just do not be tempted to do it from your computer (that can be tracked).

Comment: and don't have multiple people say the same things, or use the same phrases.  it actually is really easy to spot the manufactured reviews on new apps, just read them with that possibility in mind.  I saw one recently where three different people posted mostly the EXACT same review word for word with only minor changes to the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if all you're doing is telling your friends about your app and encouraging them to post honest reviews in the App Store, that's probably fine.

If, however, you were trying to get your friends who'd never even used the app to positively review it in the App Store, that would probably be considered a breach of that rule.